# How can I evaluate the arg min/argmin of a sequence in Simulink/real-time?

Tags: matlab, correlation

I am wondering whether someone could give me some hints on how to evaluate/implement the math function arg min/argmin in Simulink.

Let's say that I have the following expression

$$ \hat{y_{16}}:\min_{x}(I_{16}(x)<0) $$

where $I_{16}(x)$ is a scaled version of 16 autocorrelation from $x$

I am reading it as, the minimum value of $x$ that makes $I_{16}$ smaller than zero. But my question is how can I implement that in Simulink?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about mathematics.

Comment: I think, you should ask at https://stackoverflow.com/ instead.

Comment: Ok I will do so, thanks